# Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Find (with proof) the limit as $n \to \infty$ of
>   $$\int_0^n (1 + \frac x n)^{-n} x^{-1/n} dx$$

I am trying to solve this question by finding the dominating integrable function. in the class, my professor said that the function will be not easy to be found. We already found the answer is 1 if there is the dominating function. Not homework, pure curiosity. Can I get some help?

Comment: After plotting some of the $f_n(x)=(1+x/n)^{-n}x^{-1/n}$, it looks like $f_n$ is uniformly decreasing, thus $f_2$ is dominating (and it's integrable on $]0,+\infty[$). Now you have to prove this :-)

Comment: Oh, i guess i erased my question...
Again, thank you Henry!
And, thanks others for the help!

Comment: @Andrew: I just unerased it.  Next time use a comment

Answer (score 1):

For every $n\geqslant1$, consider the function $g_n$ defined on $(0,+\infty)$ by
$$
g_n(x)=\left(1 + \frac x n\right)^{-n} x^{-1/n}\,\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt n}.
$$
For every $u$ in $(0,1)$, $1+u\geqslant\mathrm e^{u\log2}$ hence $g_n\leqslant g$ for every $n\geqslant2$, where $g(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, and
$g(x)=\mathrm e^{-x\log2}$ for every $x$ in $(1,+\infty)$. Since $g$ is integrable, this is a bona fide dominating function.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not homework, I shall just tell you that the value of the integral is "just"

n^(2-1/n) Hypergeometric2F1[(n-1)/n, n, 2-1/n,-1] /(n-1)

and that, for infinite values of "n", the limit is 1 as you found. I do not know how you arrived at this conclusion and I really should like to know. Please, post.

Comment: My professor used Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem, and the inside converged to e^-x.

Comment: Probably because then you can permute the limits, and you have to compute $\int_0^{\infty} \exp (-x) \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: yes, that is how we found the answer is 1

Comment: but, would you explain a bit more on your function?
what is Hypergeometric2F1[(n-1)/n, n, 2-1/n,-1] /(n-1)?

Comment: @Andrew. This is interesting. I must now confess that I have to learn this theorem. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew. Just a nightmare ! Back to serious, it is a special function. If you are curious, just look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's not a problem, since one does not have to compute this integral explicitly: only the limit as $n\to\infty$ is asked. Also, it may happen that this hypergeometric nightmare simplifies to a simple function (most "elementary" functions, like exp, sin, etc. are hypergeometric). Sometimes this simplification is not obvious, and the answer given by a CAS is far from optimal, regarding simplicity (or they don't have the same notion of simplicity!).

Comment: @arbautjc. I totally agree with you in all your points. Cheers.